# Como puedo Optimizar el Rendimiento cuando Carga Compilado de React por Primera vez

Tags: reactjs, chrome, server-side-rendering, internet-explorer-9

tengo un Proyecto desplegado en Producción hecho con React, el problema es que en las Maquinas antiguas (Tipo Intel Inside con Dual Core), estas se demoran muchísimo en cargar.
Se que lógicamente es por el Procesador de dichos PCs, pero SI o SI se necesita utilizar el aplicativo en estas maquinas antiguas, como podría entonces optimizar el rendimiento cuando carga por primera vez????

Comment: Pregunta muy general. Yo sugiero que se analice la `App` con [Profiler](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-devtools-profiler), se puede identificar los componentes con más complejidad y a partir de ahí, comenzar un refactor. Ahora, tengo conocimiento de que el refactor en reactJS puede esta dirigido a reducir el numero de re-renders, memorizar funciones, composición de componentes.